# ruby on rails: alias for variable in model? (be able to do m.attr_a == m.attr_b as well as assignments)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

is there a way to do this

```
  def version=(version)
    self.revision = version
  end

  def version
    return self.revision
  end
```

with one line? I feel like it would be a pretty common thing to do. =\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "model" do you mean `ActiveRecord` model?

In which case YES.

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :version, :revision
end
```

will do what you want.

Else in plain Ruby

```
alias :version  :revision
alias :version= :revision=
```

Or

```
alias_method :version,  :revision
alias_method :version=, :revision=
```

Comment: this is neat. is there a way to also include parameters for alias_method? like alias_method :latest_revision, :revision_at(nil) ?

Comment: I think at that point you're better off just writing the method `def latest_revision; revision_at(nil); end`